# In WPF how do I implement ICommandSource to give my custom control ability to use Command from xaml?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, routed-commands

Could you please provide a sample, of how do you implement the `ICommandSource` interface. As I want my `UserControl`, which doesn't have the ability to Specify command in xaml, to have this ability. And to be able to handle the command when user clicks on the `CustomControl`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here's an example :

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl, ICommandSource
{
    public MyUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }



    public ICommand Command
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(CommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CommandProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Command", typeof(ICommand), typeof(MyUserControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));


    public object CommandParameter
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(CommandParameterProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CommandParameterProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for CommandParameter.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandParameterProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("CommandParameter", typeof(object), typeof(MyUserControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    public IInputElement CommandTarget
    {
        get { return (IInputElement)GetValue(CommandTargetProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CommandTargetProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for CommandTarget.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandTargetProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("CommandTarget", typeof(IInputElement), typeof(MyUserControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));


    protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(e);

        var command = Command;
        var parameter = CommandParameter;
        var target = CommandTarget;

        var routedCmd = command as RoutedCommand;
        if (routedCmd != null && routedCmd.CanExecute(parameter, target))
        {
            routedCmd.Execute(parameter, target);
        }
        else if (command != null && command.CanExecute(parameter))
        {
            command.Execute(parameter);
        }
    }

}
```

Note that the `CommandTarget` property is only used for `RoutedCommands`

Answer (score 0):

Your UserControl will have a code behind file cs or vb, you have to implement the interface ICommandSource, and once you implement that, in some event you will have to actually invoke the command and also check CanExecute.